# PHP Number Ticket System?

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to make a ticket system. So a users will be assigned 1000 tickets each, I will then generate a number from 1 to 5000, I then need it to select the user.

The way I have done it was made an array then looped 5000 times and assigned each user a ticket, however this doesn't work with really big numbers like 5,000,000. So I'm trying to think of the best way to do this and I'm unsure how.

Any advice?

```
    $users = array();
$ticketNum = 0;
$result = $MySQL->query("SELECT * FROM  `users` ");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $row['points']){
        $i++;
        $ticketNum++;
        $ar = array("ticketNum" => $ticketNum, "username" => $row['username']);
        array_push($users, $ar);

    }

}

$winningTicket = 2500;

foreach($players as $ar){
    if($winningTicket == $ar['ticketNum']){
        //winner
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried to accomplish your goal. Include some of your code in your question so it is easier for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: I've added the code for an example now.

Comment: The ticket numbers seem sequential. Can't you just store an array with `$array[$ticketNum] = $user` for the first ticket and just know that that user will have tickets from `$tickenNum to $tickenNum+$row["points"]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll need more code to suggest a perfect solution, and also know why you want to assign 1000 tickets to a person?

But you could assign a from-to key instead of looping ALL of the numbers through, like

```
$users[$userNumber]["from"] = 1;
$users[$userNumber]["to"] = 6;

$findNumber = rand(1,6);

$foundUser = false;
foreach($users as $userNumber => $user) {
  if ($user["from"] <= $findNumber && $user["to"] >= $findNumber) {
    $foundUser = $user;
    break;
  }
}
if ($foundUser) {
   print "Hooray, someone just got a ticket.";
}
```

but it does sound like a job you would solve in a different manner, maybe through your database.

**Edit:** I wrote the above before you added your code example, In your case I would probably do the following.

```
$result = $MySQL->query("SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

$winningUser = $result->fetch_assoc();

print "We got a winner: ".$winningUser["username"];
```

Comment: Problem is the number needs to be specific. So that wont work.